# Reference request: quantifier elimination test

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

I'm having difficulty finding this result in the standard texts.

> **Theorem.** Let $T$ be a theory in a language $\mathcal{L}$. TFAE:
>
> 1) $T$ has quantifier elimination,
>
> 2) Whenever $M, N$ are $\aleph_1$-saturated models of $T$, $A \subset
>  M$, $B \subset N$ are countable nonempty substructures and $f : A
>  \rightarrow B$ an $\mathcal{L}$-isomorphism, then for any $a \in M$
>   there exists an extension $f' \supset f$ with $a$ in the domain of
>   $f'$ and $f'$ still an $\mathcal{L}$-isomorphism. In addition, for any
>   $b \in N$ there exists an extension $f'' \supset f$ with $b$ in the
>   range of $f''$ and $f''$ still an $\mathcal{L}$-isomorphism.

I'm obtaining this result from these notes by Chatzidakis (see 2.27): http://www.math.ens.fr/~zchatzid/papiers/CUP-MT.pdf. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You really mean to replace $\aleph_1$-saturated by $|{\mathcal L}|^+$-saturated.    Also, it suffices to consider just the forth direction.  That is, the last sentence beginning "In addition" may be dropped.

Comment: You are correct, I had a particular example in mind while typing and did not adjust for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this formulation with $\omega_1$-saturated models is in any of the "main standard" texts. But there is a complete treatment in these [course notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~apillay/pdf/lecturenotes_modeltheory.pdf) by Pillay (see Proposition 2.29).

If you're looking for something in a standard published text, Corollary 3.1.6 of *Model Theory: An Introduction* (Marker) is along the same lines. It says:

> Let $T$ be an $L$-theory. Suppose that for all quantifier-free formulas $\phi(\bar{v},w)$, if $M,N\models T$, $A$ is a common substructure of $M$ and $N$, $\bar{a}\in A$, and there is $b\in M$ such that $M\models\phi(\bar{a},b)$, then there is $c\in N$ such that $N\models \phi(\bar{a},c)$. Then $T$ has quantifier elimination.

It is not too difficult to deduce the theorem you quoted from this.

Comment: Also, see Proposition 4.3.28 in my book {\em Model Theory: an Introduction}.

Comment: I stand corrected...there it is. And the proof does reduce to 3.1.6. Thanks Dave!